# C.Heapsort .Count the number of swaps and comparisons

Tags: c, sorting, heap, swap, heapsort

The sorting seems to be working correctly. At least it sorts correctly :) It remains only to count the number of comparisons and swaps. How to calculate and output it?Somehow stalled at this point.. I will be very grateful for your help.If you demonstrate it with the updated code , I will be doubly grateful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void keyDown(int* arr, int n, int head)
{
    int j;
    if(2*head + 2 < n && arr[2*head + 1] < arr[2*head + 2])
    {
        j = 2*head + 2; 
    }
    else j = 2*head + 1;

    while(arr[head] < arr[j] && head < n / 2)
    {
        int tmp = arr[head];
        arr[head] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = tmp;
    
        head = j;

        if(2*head + 2 < n && arr[2*head + 1] < arr[2*head + 2])
        {
            j = 2*head + 2; 
        }
        else j = 2*head + 1;
    }

}
void heapSort(int* arr, int n)
{  
    int i;
    for(i = n/2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        keyDown(arr,n,i);
    }
    int l = n;
    while(l > 1)
    {  
        l--;
        
        int tmp = arr[l];
        arr[l] = arr[0];
        arr[0] = tmp;
        
        keyDown(arr,l,0);
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n=10;
    int start, end,i;
    int *arr;
        arr=(int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
        time_t invocation_time = time(NULL);
        srand(invocation_time);
        int s;
        for (s=0;s<n;s++)
        {
            arr[s] = rand() % 50;
            printf ("%d \n", arr[s]);
        }
        printf ("\n");  
        heapSort(arr, n);
        for (i=0;i<n;i++){
            printf ("%d \n", arr[i]);   
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> count the number of comparisons and swaps

make functions

```
//global counters
unsigned comparisons = 0, swaps = 0;

int lessthan(int a, int b) {
    comparisons++;
    return (a < b);
}
void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    swaps++;
    int tmp = *a; *a = *b; *b = tmp;
}
```

and then replace comparisons and swaps in your existing code with the specific function you need.

```
int main(int argc, char **argc) {
    //...
    if (lessthan(a[i], a[j])) swap(a+i, a+j);
    //...
    printf("comparisons: %u; swaps: %u\n", comparisons, swaps);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, but I think I did something wrong :(
For some reason, I always get the fixed numbers 1 and 0.
Could you supplement my code with your own, but so that it works correctly, if it's not difficult for you, of course?Thanks anyway.

Comment: @LusindaBabaika: I took the liberty of reformating your code a little bit (for my preferences): https://ideone.com/GL2BvK

Comment: thank you very much, I hope I understand everything!

Comment: It's just basically simply replacing code with `<` with a call to `lessthan()` and rewriting expressions, ie: `foo >= bar` ==> `foo + 1 > bar` ==> `lessthan(bar, foo + 1)`. I could have written a function `greaterorequal()`. Feel free to ask about any problems you have.

Comment: I may have missed something, but look at this, please.For some reason, the program ends prematurely and an empty file is created.I wanted to create a file with statistics on sorting.For 100 elements, for 200, etc.And I take the average of the sum of swaps and comparisons over 5 executions.But something is wrong https://ideone.com/CUB6XA

Comment: It works for me (I just changed line 60): https://ideone.com/Xgk6kf. Note that the counters keep accumulating, they never reset to `0`.

Comment: https://postimg.cc/MfBx2MKR I get a result for 100 numbers in the console, and then the program stops working.I don't understand what's going on.I just need an excel file.I saw what works for you, but for some reason I can't solve this problem... :'''/

Comment: Latest version: https://ideone.com/iNqEHh ... I have no idea why it stops after `100` for you